# How can I make a constrained linear model by group in df?

Tags: r

I need to make a constrained model by group in R. I tried the group_by and do() functions to estimate the unconstrained lm, but when I try the same for a constrained model with ConsReg it doesn´t work.

This worked for the unconstrained lm:

```
df_grouped <- df %>% 
    group_by(type, Region)
grouped_lm <- df_grouped %>%  
    do(tidy(lm(y ~ x, data =.)))
```

For the constrained model I tried this:

```
grouped_lm_constrained <- df_grouped %>% 
    do(ConsReg(formula = y ~ x, family = 'gaussian', optimizer = 'mcmc', LOWER = 0, UPPER = 1, data =.))
```

but gives me this error:

```
"Error in `do()`:
! Results 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... must be data frames, not ConsReg."
```

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `df` (perhaps the output of `dput(df)`) that replicates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing stems from the `broom::tidy` function, which has no implementation for `ConsReg` models/objects. What you could do is write your custom function for extraction of the desired content from a `ConsReg` model/object. To know what the model object has in its belly you can i.e. generate just one model (one group) and call `str(model)` on it as well as `str(summary(model))` to see what base R can do for you in terms of structuring the data. In the example below I extracted a not selection of what could be importante model content. You might have to adapt this according to your usecase and needs.

I really like the aproach of nested lists in tibbles and running models on those. Anyhow you can run the `do()` approach or even split the `data.frame` into a list where each item is a group and work mapping functions for example on those.

```
library(ConsReg)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

# Dummy data
df <- data.frame(g = sort(rep(c("A", "B") , "10")),
                 x = rep(1:10, 2),
                 y = c(1:10, seq(from = 1, to = 100, by = 10)))

# custom function which takes a model as input and parses the formula, coefficients plus aditional data and MAPE as a data.frame
myfun <- function(x){
      cbind(fromula = x$formula %>% deparse, 
            as.data.frame(summary(x)$coefficients) %>% tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% dplyr::rename(Term = 1),
            MAPE = x$metrics$MAPE)
}

# group the df for nesting in the next step
dplyr::group_by(df, g) %>%
    # nest the columns of interest into a list where each item (aka group) contains the mentioned variables
    tidyr::nest(data = c("x", "y")) %>%
    # run run map functions on data to generate model and the custom extraction function 
    dplyr::mutate(crmod = purrr::map(data, ~ ConsReg(y ~ x, family = 'gaussian', optimizer = 'mcmc', LOWER = 0, UPPER = 1, data = .x)),
                  stats = purrr::map(crmod, ~ myfun(.x))) %>%
    # unnest the stats column from list items do df row(s)
    tidyr::unnest(stats) 

# Groups:   g [2]
  g     data              crmod     fromula Term        Estimate   StdErr t.value  p.value     MAPE
  <chr> <list>            <list>    <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 A     <tibble [10 x 2]> <ConsReg> y ~ x   (Intercept) 1.12e-15 7.79e-16    1.44 1.87e- 1 1.87e-16
2 A     <tibble [10 x 2]> <ConsReg> y ~ x   x           1   e+ 0 1.03e- 1    9.67 1.09e- 5 1.87e-16
3 B     <tibble [10 x 2]> <ConsReg> y ~ x   (Intercept) 9.84e- 1 3.03e- 2   32.5  8.79e-10 8.58e- 1
4 B     <tibble [10 x 2]> <ConsReg> y ~ x   x           9.98e- 1 7.83e- 3  128.   1.59e-14 8.58e- 1
```